# VB.NET Pointer to value types

Tags: vb.net, pointers, value-type, byref

VB.NET 2010, .NET 4

Hello all,

I'm by no means a good programmer and I'm just trying to wrap my head around some of this stuff, so please forgive me if this is a dumb question.

I want the following to produce a message box that says "2", not "5":

```
Public Class SomeClass
  Private SomeInt As Integer = 5
  Private SomeListOfInts As New List(Of Integer)

  Public Sub New()
    SomeListOfInts.Add(SomeInt)
    SomeListOfInts(0) = 2
    MsgBox(SomeInt.ToString)
  End Sub
End Class
```

This doesn't work.  The message box says "5".  I think that I understand why to some degree.  Since SomeInt is a value type, adding it to SomeListOfInts just adds a copy.  I'm sorry if this is incoherent.  Is there any straightforward way to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance,
Brian

Edit:  I just wanted to add, I suspect folks'll say "Why try to do this?"/"This is not a good thing to try to do." etc.  I'm alright with that and would like to know a better approach if there is one, however, I am also generically curious about how something like this might be done, whether it's good practice or not.  Also, if it isn't good practice (whatever that means), why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is output 5 because your MsgBox is referencing `SomeInt`, **not** `SomeListOfInts(0)`

Try this:

```
Public Class SomeClass
  Private SomeInt As Integer = 5
  Private SomeListOfInts As New List(Of Integer)

  Public Sub New()
    SomeListOfInts.Add(SomeInt)
    SomeListOfInts(0) = 2
    MsgBox(SomeListOfInts(0).ToString) // here is the change
  End Sub
End Class
```

This...

```
SomeListOfInts(0) = 2
```

changes indexed element 0 in your list from 5 (the original value of element 0) to 2. Also, `int` is a value type. Therefore, when you add `SomeInt` to the list, you have created a copy of the value type. The copy can be changed without affecting the original `SomeInt`.

You could start with:

Private ListOfInts As New List(Of Integer)

```
Public Sub New(SomeInt As Integer)
    ListOfInts.Add(SomeInt)

    ' processes

    ListOfInts(0) = 2
    MsgBox(SomeListOfInts(0).ToString)
End Sub
```

Maybe with a little more background on exactly what you are trying to do, I can help you get closer to your expectations.

Comment: The fact that "the copy can be changed without affecting the original" is exactly my problem.  I *want* to affect the original.  I think what I want is a list that would store *references* to integers so that I can change the original variable via something like SomeListOfInts(0) = 2 *instead* of changing a copy.

Comment: Essentially, I want the line SomeListOfInts(0) = 2 to change the value of SomeInt to 2.  I've been reading about IntPtr, but it's over my head and certainly beyond the realm of what I want to try.